# how do i reshare a facebook post

Tags: facebook

Wife just switched from Android to windows phone and in her old phone Facebook posts all had a share button for resharing other people's posts she followed. Cannot for the life of me find that functionality in windows phone.

Anybody know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't in the app you download from the store, but it is there if you access FB via a web page (http://m.facebook.com)